# Pre-appending row value to a Range

Tags: listbox

I am filling a listbox with values, and simply want them to show up numbered. I get my range from a sheet, and just want to sneak in a loop counter, then load the range. The numbering doesn't exist on the raw data sheet, so I choose this route. Here's the original code:

```
 Dim myArray As Variant
 numbldsec = Worksheets("bld").Cells(2, 1).Value
 myArray = Worksheets("bld").Range("A3:A" & numbldsec + 2)
 With Worksheets("plots")
  .ListBox1.List = myArray
  .ListBox1.IntegralHeight = False
  .ListBox1.IntegralHeight = True
  .ListBox1.Height = 45
  .ListBox1.Width = 69
  .ListBox1.Top = 0
  .ListBox1.Left = 1255.5
 End With
```

So I want myArray to have 2 values per row....

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, this worked:

```
Dim myArray As Variant
numbldsec = Worksheets("bld").Cells(2, 1).Value
myArray = Worksheets("bld").Range("A3:A" & numbldsec + 2).Value
For i = 1 To numbldsec ' pre-append radii with section numbers
 myArray(i, 1) = i & " " & myArray(i, 1)
Next i
```

etc...